# maven will change my project's name, how to stop it?

Tags: java, maven, svn, intellij-idea

I'm trying to import a maven project , but `intellij-idea` will change my project's name by maven's actifactId.

I have searched many method to solve it , but I find the only useful method that is to change the **.iml** files' name manually.

It's wasting my time to do the job .

So how can I solve it effectively?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Though I can understand what you are facing, but could you update the question with the artifact name and the project name that you're using.

Comment: Also a screenshot of such renaming occurrence shall work.

Comment: what's the problem with using the artifact id as the project name? You don't like things that make sense?

Comment: sounds like you need more logical artifact-id's... ;) worst case, just rename it. importing a project is a one-of ocurrence, after all.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ's behaviour here is quite standard but if you really cannot change the `artifactId` and if the name derived from the `artifactId` is really not acceptable then you can either:

- Choose a different name in the last step of the `Import Project` wizard
- Change the IntelliJ project name from `File > Project Structure`. Note: this is only allowed if you create the project with `Project format: .idea (directory based)`, you can choose the project format on the second step of the `Import Project` wizard. Here are some example screenshots:

[image]

[image]

In the second screenshot the `Name` field is editable.